# How to speed up a nested loop with hundreds of thousands of combinations records in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, combinations, nested-for-loop

Consider I've two data frames GL_df and RE_df

| GL_ID | GL_ACCNO | GL_DATE | GL_CRDR | GL_AMOUNT | ISMATCHED | MATCH_TABLE | MATCH_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1175595887 | 0004366490004 | 2022-03-14 | C | 17482.12 | 0 | NULL | NULL |
| 1175595893 | 0004366490004 | 2022-03-14 | D | -91.22 | 0 | NULL | NULL |
| 1175595897 | 0004366490004 | 2022-03-14 | D | -18.24 | 0 | NULL | NULL |
| 1179466130 | 0004366490004 | 2022-03-22 | D | -400000.00 | 0 | NULL | NULL |
| 1179466158 | 0004366490004 | 2022-03-22 | D | -500000.00 | 0 | NULL | NULL |

| RE_ID | RE_ACCNO | RE_DATE | RE_CRDR | RE_AMOUNT | ISMATCHED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1261337 | 0004366490004 | 2022-03-22 | C | 500000.00 | 0 |
| 1261342 | 0004366490004 | 2022-03-22 | D | -44707.99 | 0 |
| 1261343 | 0004366490004 | 2022-03-22 | D | -16226.15 | 0 |
| 1261346 | 0004366490004 | 2022-03-22 | D | -17338.43 | 0 |
| 1261348 | 0004366490004 | 2022-03-22 | C | 500000.00 | 0 |

In the above

1. I've to find all possible combinations of Id's of two dataframe where IS_MATCHED columns value equals to zero

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Max_per_com = 4
dict_data = GL_df.loc[GL_df['ISMATCHED']==0].set_index('GL_ID')['GL_AMOUNT'].to_dict()
GL_per_com_list = [i for j in range(Max_per_com) for i in combinations(dict_data, j) if sum(map(dict_data.get, i))]

dict_data = RE_df.loc[RE_df['ISMATCHED']==0].set_index('RE_ID')['RE_AMOUNT'].to_dict()
RE_per_com_list = [i for j in range(Max_per_com) for i in combinations(dict_data, j) if sum(map(dict_data.get, i))]
```

2. filter and sum all possible combination amounts from GL_df Id's with RE_df ID's, the amount with in the Variance level mark it as matched and skip it for further combinations

   - skip the already matched records from both tables
   - here GL_df,RE_df date (format '%m/%Y') count should be 1
   - also GL_df,RE_df date (format '%m/%Y') should be same

```
Variance = 1

for i in range(0,len(GL_per_com_list)):
    if 1 in (GL_df[GL_df['GL_ID'].isin(list(GL_per_com_list[i]))]['ISMATCHED'].values):
        continue
    if len(GL_df[GL_df['GL_ID'].isin(list(GL_per_com_list[i]))]['GL_DATE'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y').unique()) > 1:
        continue
    for j in range(0,len(RE_per_com_list)):
        if 1 in (RE_df[RE_df['RE_ID'].isin(list(RE_per_com_list[j]))]['ISMATCHED'].values):
            continue
        if len(RE_df[RE_df['RE_ID'].isin(list(RE_per_com_list[j]))]['RE_DATE'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y').unique()) > 1:
            continue
        if ((GL_df[GL_df['GL_ID'].isin(list(GL_per_com_list[i]))]['GL_DATE'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y').unique()[0]) != (RE_df[RE_df['RE_ID'].isin(list(RE_per_com_list[j]))]['RE_DATE'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y').unique()[0])):
            continue
        amount = abs((GL_df[GL_df['GL_ID'].isin(list(GL_per_com_list[i]))]['GL_AMOUNT'].sum()) + (RE_df[RE_df['RE_ID'].isin(list(RE_per_com_list[j]))]['RE_AMOUNT'].sum()))
        if amount <= Variance:
            GL_df.loc[GL_df['GL_ID'].isin(list(GL_per_com_list[i])),'ISMATCHED'] = 1
            RE_df.loc[RE_df['RE_ID'].isin(list(RE_per_com_list[j])),'ISMATCHED'] = 1
            GL_df.loc[GL_df['GL_ID'].isin(list(GL_per_com_list[i])),'MATCH_TABLE'] = 'tbl$matched$entry'
            GL_df.loc[GL_df['GL_ID'].isin(list(GL_per_com_list[i])),'MATCH_ID'] = str(list(RE_per_com_list[j]))
            break
```

The above cases it works as expected. but it will take hours to perform. I just wan't to speed it up with in seconds or minutes

Comment: Seeking your help to close this soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank God, Big thanks to Myself

Gone through the internet and got some idea. To process millions of records in efficient way you need to convert the data into **Python Dictionary or JSON data**. here I converted the data frame to json and performed the above logic in json data which reduces my processing in seconds

```
GL_df['G_Date'] = GL_df['GL_DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
RE_df['R_Date'] = RE_df['RE_DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
GL_dict = GL_df.to_json(orient='records')
RE_dict = RE_df.to_json(orient='records')

# Transform json input to python objects
import json
GL_dict = json.loads(GL_dict)
RE_dict = json.loads(RE_dict)
```

```
for i in range(0,len(GL_per_com_list)):
    if (len([k for k in [dt for dt in GL_dict if dt['GL_ID'] in list(GL_per_com_list[i])] if k['ISMATCHED'] == 1]) > 0):
        continue
    if (len(set(k['G_Date'] for k in [dt for dt in GL_dict if dt['GL_ID'] in list(GL_per_com_list[i])])) > 1):
        continue
    for j in range(0,len(RE_per_com_list)):
        if (len([k for k in [dt for dt in RE_dict if dt['RE_ID'] in list(RE_per_com_list[j])] if k['ISMATCHED'] == 1]) > 0):
            continue
        if (len(set(k['R_Date'] for k in [dt for dt in RE_dict if dt['RE_ID'] in list(RE_per_com_list[j])])) > 1):
            continue
        if (set(k['G_Date'] for k in [dt for dt in GL_dict if dt['GL_ID'] in list(GL_per_com_list[i])]) != set(k['R_Date'] for k in [dt for dt in RE_dict if dt['RE_ID'] in list(RE_per_com_list[j])])):
            continue
        amount = abs(sum(k['GL_AMOUNT'] for k in [dt for dt in GL_dict if dt['GL_ID'] in list(GL_per_com_list[i])]) + sum(k['RE_AMOUNT'] for k in [dt for dt in RE_dict if dt['RE_ID'] in list(RE_per_com_list[j])]))
        if amount <= Variance:
            for k in [dt for dt in GL_dict if dt['GL_ID'] in list(GL_per_com_list[i])]:
                k['ISMATCHED'] = 1
                k['MATCH_TABLE'] = 'tbl$matched$entry'
                k['MATCH_ID'] = str(list(RE_per_com_list[j]))

            for k in [dt for dt in RE_dict if dt['RE_ID'] in list(RE_per_com_list[j])]:
                k['ISMATCHED'] = 1
            break
```

In the above the execution time is about four and half seconds for 200 thousand records

[image: pic1]

But in the earliest, pandas data frame filter took around 13 mins

[image: pic2]

Comment: More efficient then the above are always welcome